# Listas contar quantidade total e maior repetição

Tags: python

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para contar a quantidade de itens em um vetor, e também mostrar o numero que mais aparece.
Exemplo: dado o vetor [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
São 10 elementos 
8(numero com mais repetição )

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível utilizar esse comando importando o pacote [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode)

segue a solução:

```
import statistics
a =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]
len(a)
#10
statistics.mode(a)
#8
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> vetor = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]

>>> c = collections.Counter(vetor)
>>> print(c)
Counter({8: 3, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1})

>>> print(c.most_common(1))
[(8, 3)]
```

Isso significa que o 8 é o mais comum, aparecendo 3 vezes.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) especificando `vetor.count` no parâmetro `key` para buscar a moda da lista.

```
vetor = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8]

print ("tamanho: {}, moda: {}".format(len(vetor), max(vetor, key = vetor.count)))
```

[Rodando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DrySadMatch)

Existe o risco de haver mais de um número repetindo mais vezes, por exemplo, e nesse caso vai retornar o que aparece primeiro na lista.

Comment: Apesar de não fazer diferença nesse simples exemplo, gostaria de comentar que este código é "quadrático", ou seja, ele procura na lista toda cada elemento da lista, varrendo a mesma O² vezes. Se a lista for grande isso pode demorar bastante.

Comment: Acredito que você quis dizer O(n^2). A ideia da resposta é ter uma alternativa para não precisar importar um pacote externo. Em um pacote externo é mais difícil saber a complexidade a não ser que você tenha uma documentação ou olhe o código. Talvez uma alternativa O(n log n) seja possível escrevendo o próprio algoritmo.

Comment: No caso, o pacote não é externo. Tanto o módulo `collections` quanto `statistics` das outras respostas, são parte integrante do python oficial.

Comment: Me expressei mal. Pacote externo quis dizer importar um pacote, seja da lib que vem com o Python ou de terceiros. Com os comandos nativos você consegue entender melhor o que ele vai fazer, com um pacote você precisa ir mais a fundo para saber a complexidade. Por exemplo, nesse `collections.Counter` como eu sei a complexidade que está rodando pra criar o dicionário com cada item e sua contagem?